# html email gaps appearing in gmail after table ends

Tags: html, email, gmail, html-table

I have an issue with HTML email where gmail is puts a gap after my tables. It has been driving me crazy and tried nesting my tables in all kind of different way. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>


<body bgcolor="#000000" yahoo="fix">

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="margin:0 auto">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td width="600" style="background-color:#fafafa" bgcolor="#fafafa">
    <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td width="600">
        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#000000" style="background-color:#000000;margin:0 auto">
         <tr><td>
          <table align="top" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" height="auto">
           <tr>
            <td valign="bottom" width="600">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="top">
                  <a href="#">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="600" align="center">
                            <img height="80" src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/26000000/Garfield-garfield-26077854-262-256.gif" width="600" style="display:block;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="600" align="center">
                            <img alt="" height="820" src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/26000000/Garfield-garfield-26077854-262-256.gif" width="600" style="display:block;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="600" align="center">
                            <img height="225" src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/26000000/Garfield-garfield-26077854-262-256.gif" width="600" style="display:block;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  </a>
                </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body></html>
```

And this is how it looks like in gmail. I am trying to get rid of the black bar at the end of my html email. Seems to be very difficult... [image]

Comment: Here is a demo of your code. http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/BQPVaY Do you mean the border around the page?

Comment: i still see a black bar. weird.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML tags such as the `table`, `tbody` and `tr` did not close properly. I tried to send to myself via mailchimp with the updated one and no black bars I see from gmail's interface. 
Updated one:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#000000" yahoo="fix">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
    align="center" style="margin:0 auto">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="600" style="background-color:#fafafa" bgcolor=
          "#FAFAFA">
            <table width="600" border="0" align="center"
            cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td width="600">
                    <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing=
                    "0" border="0" bgcolor="#000000" style=
                    "background-color:#000000;margin:0 auto">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table align="top" border="0"
                          cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width=
                          "600" height="auto">
                            <tr>
                              <td valign="bottom" width="600">
                                <a href="#"></a>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0"
                                cellspacing="0" width="600" align=
                                "top">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td width="600" align="center">
                                      <img height="80" src=
                                      "http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/26000000/Garfield-garfield-26077854-262-256.gif"
                                      width="600" style=
                                      "display:block;" />
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td width="600" align="center">
                                      <img alt="" height="820" src=
                                      "http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/26000000/Garfield-garfield-26077854-262-256.gif"
                                      width="600" style=
                                      "display:block;" />
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td width="600" align="center">
                                      <img height="225" src=
                                      "http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/26000000/Garfield-garfield-26077854-262-256.gif"
                                      width="600" style=
                                      "display:block;" />
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```